# Array initialization syntax in method call

Tags: c#, syntax

Having the code below, why is the variable declaration considered as correct syntax, but not also the method call?

```
public static void Func(string[] p)
{
}

public static void Test()
{
    string[] a = { "x", "y", "z" };
    Func({"x", "y", "z"});
}
```

Comment: You could use `new [] {"x", "y", "z"}`

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it at the moment. The basic answer is "because the language specification says so"...

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621250/why-are-collection-initializers-on-re-assignments-not-allowed?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like everybody else is focusing on the workaround (which is simply to specify that you need a `new [] { "some", "strings" }`. The why is a little less obvious though.

The former is valid because the compiler knows to use your initialization syntax to create an Array (because you've defined it as such).

The later would have some issues. It may seem trivial in this case because the compiler should, theoretically, be able to figure out that you need a `string[]`. Think about cases where you have a `Func<IEnumerable<string>>` though. What type gets generated in that case? Would the compiler take a wild-ass guess? Always use an Array (even though there might be a better fit)? It could be one of a number of possibilities.

I'm guessing that's the reason that the language specification doesn't allow for passing things this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a value as the argument. `{"x", "y", "z"}` is **not** a value. It can be used as short-hand for initializing a variable.

Note that both of these are valid:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>() {"x", "y", "z"};
string[] b = new string[] {"x", "y", "z"};
```

And the full version of what it represents:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.Add("x");
a.Add("y");
a.Add("z");
```

So you need to make an object (`new`)

```
new [] {"x", "y", "z"}
```

Or make an object beforehand and pass that in.

As for *why* this is like this, you need to pass in a value, not a helper for array initialization.

Comment: That does not answer question *WHY array initializer cannot be used on its own*

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, "because the c# language said so". Does anyone know the real reason?

Comment: @gunr2171 Because the feature was not thought of, designed, tested, implemented, and shipped.  It stopped somewhere along that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the object directly on the inside of the method call, but do not think a good practice.

where you used:

```
Func ({"x", "y", "z"});
```

The above form you tried to pass an object not instantiated, ie it does not already exist on your "context". The correct is you initialize it to be generated in a reference memory to this value and thus the "Func" method you can use it.

In the case of variable declaration:

```
string[] a = {"x", "y", "z"};
```

In this case your compiler is reading:

```
string[] a = new string[] {"x", "y", "z"};
```

It does this interpretation alone, without requiring you to do object initialization explicitly.

So my answer is best for this situation you must first create the object then pass it as a parameter to the method:

```
  string[] a = {"x", "y", "z"}; 
  Func (s);
```