# What is the proper method of defining variables?

Tags: c#

Why define this

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

When you can define like this?

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The latter is just syntactic sugar for the former. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Can you please explain that can be understand by beginners?

Comment: Syntactic Sugar is just functionallity that the compiler provides to allow you  to write things in an easier/shorter way. The code actually compiled is similar to your second option

Comment: Essentially, they do the same thing, pick your favourite

Comment: Another option: `var array = new [] {1,2,3};` They all do the same thing.

Comment: But why?! Why does the creator of c# needs to have this "Syntactic sugar"?

Comment: To help out code optimizers/analyzers. (Not really though.)

Comment: to let developers write code faster

Comment: Because more options will help developers who are familiar in a different language to learn the ropes of C#. A beginner might want to use `int[] array = new int[]...` so s/he can see exactly what's going on. Later, as a more experienced developer you might want o use `var array = new[]...` because you already know what's going on and it's just easier to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel like taking risk to answer that but..

From $12.6 Array initializers in [C# 5.0 Language Spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029);

> The context in which an array initializer is used determines the type
>   of the array being initialized. In an array creation expression, the
>   array type immediately precedes the initializer, or is inferred from
>   the expressions in the array initializer. In a field or variable
>   declaration, the array type is the type of the field or variable being
>   declared. When an array initializer is used in a field or variable
>   declaration, such as:
>
> `int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};`
>
> it is **simply shorthand for an equivalent array creation
>   expression**:
>
> `int[] a = new int[] {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};`

As other says, this can be called a syntactic sugar for this initializers.

> But why?! Why does the creator of c# needs to have this "Syntactic
>   sugar"?

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) states this as well.

> In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming
>   language that is designed **to make things easier to read or to express**.
>   It makes the language **"sweeter" for human use**: things can be expressed
>   **more clearly**, **more concisely**, or in an alternative style that **some may
>   prefer**.

So, what is the proper method? *Well*, that question is subjective. Some *may* prefer first, some *may* prefer second, or even some *may* prefer `var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };` based on your example. [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is also a syntactic sugar which comes C# 3.0 version. But with this, you can not write `var array = { 1, 2, 3 };` since it can complicate the parser as [Eric Lippert noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354144/447156).

By the way, you can find [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5678216/447156) in here and [What is the difference between “Syntax” and “Syntactic Sugar”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/194007/16620) in Programming.SE.

Also I have to write this [lovely comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194007/what-is-the-difference-between-syntax-and-syntactic-sugar#comment374970_194007) by Anthony Pegram in Programming.SE;

> In the end, it's all just syntatic sugar over electricity.

Comment: This kind of answer is what I'm looking for. Thanks mate!